# Sufficient Conditions for Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

In [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-elementary-proof-of-the-strong-law-of-large-Etemadi/e61cd2d6b8cd9e964d2fb01146d20aca606d9e87), I found that if $\lbrace X_i \rbrace$ is an independenly indentically distributed (i.i.d.) sequence and $E(|X_i|)<\infty$, then $\bar{X}_{N}=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{X_i}{N}$ converge to $E(X_i)$ almost surely, i.e. $P(\lim_{N\to\infty}\bar{X}_N=E(X_i))=1$.

I have this counter-example in my mind: $X_i\overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} N\times Bernoulli(\frac{1}{N})$, i.e. each $X_i$ takes the value $N$ with probability $\frac{1}{N}$ and $0$ otherwise. Obviously $E(|X_i|)=E(X_i)=1<\infty$. Note that $Var(X_i)=O(N)$ and hence $Var(\bar{X}_{N})=O(1)>0$. Therefore, $P(\lim_{N\to\infty}\bar{X}_N=E(X_i))\neq 1$.

I am wondering whether one should replace $E(|X_i|)<\infty$ with the condition that $\lbrace X_{i,N}\rbrace$ to be uniformly integrable: $\lim_{c\to\infty}\sup_N \sup_{1\leq i\leq N} E(|X_{i,N}|I(X_{i,N}>c))=0$, where $I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function equal to $1$ when $X_i>c$ and $0$ otherwise, to rule out my counter-example.

Comment: Your example is of a triangular array of random variables.  That is, a sequence of finite sequences $(X_{N,1},...X{N,N})$, and not a single infinite sequence of iid rvs $X_1,X_2,...$

Comment: You mentioned the i..i.d. condition, but in you have constructed an example without identical distribution.

Comment: $X_i$ is i.i.d. over $i$ for a given $N$.

Comment: To rule out my counter-example, should I phrase the SLLN as follows? If $\lbrace X_i\rbrace, i=1,2,\dots,N$, is an i.i.d. sequence and $\lbrace X_{i,N}\rbrace$ is uniformly integrable, then $P(\lim_{N\to\infty} \bar{X}_{N}=E(X_i))=1$.